# How to send multiple AID from a Payment App to a Terminal?

Tags: android, contactless-smartcard, emv, tlv

I want to send multiple AID to the terminal from my android payment application. For doing so how to construct a response message of the select command?

Suppose I am getting 00 A4 04 00 0E (14 bytes data) 00  from the terminal. In response, I am sending 6F23840E(14 bytes data)A511BF0C0E610C4F07A00000000310108701019000 . Here my AID is A0000000031010. If I try to concatenate two AID, terminal immediately cancel the transaction. I tried with the following response message for concatenation: 6F30840E325041592E5359532E4444463031A51EBF0C1B61194F07A00000000310108701024F08A0000000031010018701019000.

I have checked the TLV using TLV Parser. Link :https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=6F30840E325041592E5359532E4444463031A51EBF0C1B61194F07A00000000310108701024F08A0000000031010018701019000

Can you suggest me how to send multiple AID list to terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Generally any Payment application returns only its own AID in the response of SELECT command for this application (in Tag 84).This might be the reason that terminal is terminating the processing when you are sending multiple AIDs.
It seems like you want to return multiple VISA AIDs.
you can achieve this with the help of PSE/PPSE kind of applications. In PSE and PPSE you can return multiple AID to terminal and then terminal will issue the SELECT command further to select the available application.
Refer EMV book 1 for response construction of PSE/PPSE or any application.   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Currently I am using SLECT_PPSE command to send the AID to the terminal. But can't figure out how to send multiple one. Can you please suggest me a specific way or specific page number from EMV book ??

Comment: @faysal this was what I had given in my post. Did you check 1, 12.2.2 Structure of the PSE  and  12.3.2 Using the PSE. Its is more or less same for contactless also. Anyone developing in emv should download and keep handy, books 1, 2, 4, and 4 along with contactless specifications from emvco. In your case check for PPSE.

Comment: Hi faysal, I have added one snapshot. Hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score -3):

Download EMV Book 1,2,3,4,B,C from [emvco](https://www.emvco.com/document-search/?action=search_documents&publish_date=&emvco_document_version=&emvco_document_book=&px_search=book&emvco_document_technology%5B%5D=contact&emvco_document_technology%5B%5D=contactless&emvco_document_specifications%5B%5D=specifications). These are specifications all expected to adhere to.

Check

- 12.2.2 Structure of the PSE, and
- 12.3.2 Using the PSE

  sections. It has got detailed explanation on PSE. PPSE also works the same way. Go through the above docs, those are great and precise, i have used them for developing an NFC terminal on android mobile.